# Bluemix Does Not Include instance_id in VCAP_APPLICATION

Tags: spring, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud

I ran

```
cf env <my app>
```

and noticed that Bluemix was not returning a value for `instance_id` in the returned JSON data for the `VCAP_APPLICATION` object. My application was running on Bluemix with multiple instances. Most of the other attributes including `application_id` and `application_name` were present.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.run.pivotal.io/devguide/deploy-apps/environment-variable.html#VCAP-APPLICATION), it sounds like all the attributes should always be present:

> This variable contains the associated attributes for a deployed
>   application. Results are returned in JSON format. The table below
>   lists the attributes that are returned.

The problem I encountered was that [Spring Cloud](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-connectors) will not work if some of the required attributes are missing. Am I correct in thinking the fact that `instance_id` is omitted is a bug in Bluemix?

I did confirm after adding a dummy value to `VCAP_APPLICATION` that Spring Cloud works correctly with Bluemix.

---

Update -- adding exact error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:459)
    at org.springframework.cloud.Cloud.getAppProperties(Cloud.java:252)
    at org.springframework.cloud.Cloud.getCloudProperties(Cloud.java:236)
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.java.AbstractCloudConfig.properties(AbstractCloudConfig.java:67)
```

This error occurs due to this method in a `Configuration` class that extends `AbstractCloudConfig`:

```
@Bean
public Properties cloudProperties(){
    return properties();
}
```

Comment: What was your specific problem ("will not work" is pretty vague, I'm sure you will agree)?

Comment: @DaveSyer It is a null pointer in the `Cloud` class. I'll add the exact error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluemix **does** include `instance_id` in the `VCAP_APPLICATION` environment variable.

It is not displayed when you run `cf env <app_name>` command line, but you can see it is available when you dump its value from the Java application.

I added the following piece of code to my Bluemix Java application:

```
String VCAP_APPLICATION = System.getenv("VCAP_APPLICATION");
System.out.println("VCAP_APPLICATION - " + VCAP_APPLICATION);
```

and then run following command to check recent logs:

```
$ cf logs <app-name> --recent
```

and I can see `instance_id` in the output below:

> 2016-01-05T17:05:00.01-0500 [App/0]      OUT VCAP_APPLICATION -
>   {"limits":{"mem":512,"disk":1024,"fds":16384},"application_id":"9958288f-9842-4ddc-93dd-1ea3c90634cd","application_version":"05c3b877-035f-4936-a504-cda523eb8fdf","application_name":"ads-java-cloudant","application_uris":["ads-java-cloudant.mybluemix.net"],"version":"05c3b877-035f-4936-a504-cda523eb8fdf","name":"ads-java-cloudant","space_name":"repro_alexds","space_id":"3075a3e5-2c29-4d8a-9e97-06aed18af1c6","uris":["ads-java-cloudant.mybluemix.net"],"users":null,**"instance_id":"427e4ba5851945508e6e96465e097af7"**,"instance_index":0,"host":"0.0.0.0","port":62347,"started_at":"2016-01-05
>   22:02:02 +0000","started_at_timestamp":1452031322,"start":"2016-01-05
>   22:02:02 +0000","state_timestamp":1452031322}

Answer (score 1):

Most of Spring Cloud will be fine if it doesn't know its instance id. For service discovery it is probably a good idea to have a unique identifier for an instance, but you can easily provide one yourself if you need to (e.g. `${random.int}` would work), and mostly things will work even if you don't have it, I think. For message consumers it is more important, so you probably need more customization for Spring Cloud Stream.

Comment: See Cloud.java: `appProperties.put(appPropLeadKey + "instance-id", getApplicationInstanceInfo().getInstanceId());`. That will throw a null pointer

Answer (score 0):

How many instances is your application running?
Anyway spring Cloud would accept a self managed id, so you could provide a value by your self.

Anyway you could raise a ticket to Bluemix support through the support widget describing this platform possible bug.

Comment: Running 2 instances. How would you propose to provide a value myself? Spring Cloud reads in the `VCAP_APPLICATION` env. parameter directly so it would probably involve modifying the parameter from my application before the Spring autowiring takes places which doesn't sound like a good solution unless you have something else in mind.